# How do I rebuild native Golang packages after I modify them?

Tags: go

I modified the net package and I want to use the modified version in my application but it keeps using the old code.

Comment: `$ go install net`

Comment: Or to get the entire standard library: `go install std`

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to modify the standard libraries? Updates will cause you to lose your changes, by simply putting them back you might break things.

Comment: @Bifroth May be an author want propose some changes in the `core` and want perform some test before create the pull request? Why you don't ask it about that before say that this is not a good idea? Otherwise, I think that the author is well aware that it is wrong and without that the someone will remind him about that

Comment: @mezoni you're right, I forgot about that. Sorry

Comment: @JosefHoppe I was actually told by the Go Devs to do it. They introduced a bug for certain versions and fixed it in a Beta version and told me to patch in the changes so I won't have to use Beta version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works:

```
$ go install -a net
```

It wasn't rebuilding for me either, but the -a forces a rebuild even if the toolchain thinks the specified package is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is using Docker:

My changes wasn't having effect because I was editing the package outside the container. Only the code of our project is mapped by a volume inside the container, but not the third party packages.

Once I edited the package code inside the container, I do not even had to run a `go install -a ...` like proposed by @elimisteve. It worked just by recompiling the project.